# How to add tab bar to other pages , which not in the tab bar menu

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, tabbar

I can't add tab bar to other pages, which not in the tab bar menu. When I'm adding tab bar using `UITabBar`, the content off pages overlayed to selected pages, and look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume VC1 as ViewController with TabBar & VC2 as you wish to have TabBar in.

You can use the navigation Controller for it. Just set VC1 as navigationController's root VC. If you push VC2 from VC1, you can have TabBar in VC2 as well.